# Get index of div with class equal to active

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, indexing, find

I have a twitter bootstrap carousel with :

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="item">
            <div id="container"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="item active">
            <div id="container2"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
            <div id="container3"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">«</a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">»</a>
</div>
```

Now when I click on, for ex. a button. I would like to have the index of the item with class = 'active'. In this example it would be the second div, so index = 1 (starts from 0).

To get the div with class = "active" I do this:

```
var activediv = $('.item').find('.active');
```

But when I want to find the index of the element like this:

```
var index = activediv.index();
```

I always get "-1" in my console, so he can't find the item ... But why?

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) is a function in the wrapper element.

Also `active` is not a decedent of `item`, it is a additional filter to the `item` elements - so you need to use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`

```
var activediv = $('.item').filter('.active');//or $('.item.active')
var index = activediv.index();
```

Comment: fixed that, but I still get an index of "-1". So he can't find the item. But why?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Will accept the answer when I can!

Answer (score 1):

You can always add data property to your targeted element.
Something like this.

```
<div class="item active" data-something="1">
var index=$('.active').data('something');
```